# How can I check all checkbox in my list view of android studio?

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to select all checkbox in my list view when I click select all button and deselect all checkbox when I click that button again.
I am using listview.setItemChecked,but it didn't work. How can I make the correct one?

here is my code.
myactivity.java

```
//ArrayAdapter class 
private static class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Data> {
        private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
        public static ArrayList<Data> dataList;

        public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<Data> objects) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
            layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            this.dataList = new ArrayList<Data>();
            this.dataList.addAll(objects);
        }



        private static class ViewHolder {
            TextView name;
            CheckBox selected;
        }

        @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
        public static ViewHolder holder;
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


            if (null == convertView) {
                convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.name = convertView.findViewById(R.id.NAME); //listview textbox
                holder.selected = convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1); //listview checkbox
                convertView.setTag(holder);
                holder.selected.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v ;
                    Data d = (Data) cb.getName(); //checked Name
                    d.setSelected(cb.isChecked()); //checked in checkbox
                });
            }

            else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getName();
            }

            Data dat = dataList.get(position);
            holder.name.setText(data.getName());
            holder.selected.setChecked(dat.isSelected());
            holder.selected.setTag(dat);
            return convertView;

        }

    }
```

Data.java

```
import android.widget.Checkable;

public class Data implements Checkable {

    //textview Name
    String name = null;

    //checkbox
    boolean selected = false;

    public Data(String name,boolean selected) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.selected = selected;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return selected;
    }
    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        this.selected = selected;
    }

    public void setChecked(boolean checked){
        this.selected=checked;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChecked() {
        return selected;
    }

    @Override
    public void toggle() {
        this.selected = !this.selected;
    }
}
```

When I click select all button, it can't select. Please tell me which part is wrong.
I am a beginner of android.

Edit--> It did work with below code.

```
boolean flag; // add flag for button clicked
Button mBtnSelect = root.findViewById(R.id.selectbutoon);
        mBtnSelect.setOnClickListener(view -> {


            if (!flag){
            ArrayList<Data> dataList = dataAdapter.dataList;
            for(int i=0;i<dataList .size();i++){
                Data dat= dataList .get(i);
                    dat.setChecked(true);
                }
            }           
else {
ArrayList<Data> dataList = dataAdapter.dataList;
            for(int i=0;i<dataList .size();i++){
                Data dat= dataList .get(i);
                    dat.setChecked(true);
                }
            }
            dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        });
```

Data.java

```
boolean isChecked = false;
public void setChecked(boolean checked){

        this.isChecked=checked;
    }


    public boolean isChecked() {
        return isChecked;
    }
```

I edit and add in my Data.java and call adapterlist when button is clicked. Then I checked is selected in my listview ,if it is not ,I set checked in listview. It did work.

Comment: `want to select all checkbox in my list view` Select? You mean 'check'?

Answer (score 0):

I can't catch all code cause it very hard to read, try to rewrite with meaning names for variables and reduces casts

but what you need to do >> make boolean for example `allItemsChecked` in the button pressed check if `allItemsChecked` false then for loop to the list you pass to the adapter and set every item `setChecked = true` then at adapter `notifyItemChanged()`

if `allItemsChecked` true make `setChecked = false`

Comment: hello, I edited a little. Hope you or someone can catch it well. sorry if I wrote bad code and thz you for your advice.